# Instantiate an object of a generic type in Swift

Tags: generics, swift

I am implementing a class `Foo` in Swift, that is supposed to instantiate objects of a given **subclass** of `SuperBar`, e.g. `Bar: SuperBar`. I really like generics in Swift, so I tried implementing it this way:

```
class Foo<T: SuperBar> {

    func instantiateObject() -> T {
        return T()
    }

}

class SuperBar {

}

class Bar: SuperBar {

}

let foo = Foo<Bar>()

let obj = foo.instantiateObject()
```

You can run the code snippet in an Xcode Playground and observe that `obj` is of type `SuperBar` instead of `Bar`, although it says `Bar` when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click on the constant name.

**Any Ideas?** :)

Comment: This may be a shortcoming of the current version of Swift; consider [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com). It also seems not to work if you pass the type as a parameter, like `init(_ t: T.Type) { ... t() }`

Answer (score 8):

Mark the class init as `required` and then call init :

```
class SuperBar {
    required init() {
    }
}


class Foo<T: SuperBar> {

    func instantiateObject() -> T {
        return T.init()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you add `required init() { }` to `SuperBar`, it works correctly. That requirement should always be required anyway because you are creating an instance from an variable class.

The fact that it allows you to create it using an initializer that is not required is a bug.

Comment: But it initialises a garbage (null) object

Answer (score 3):

- used `protocol` to define the blueprint of `init` method;
- other classes adopted this `Initializable` prototol have to implement `init` function
- use function with `generic type` to create instance of a type

```swift
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

class SuperBar : Initializable {
    required init() {
        print("init SuperBar")
    }
}

class Bar : SuperBar {
    required init() {
        print("init Bar")
    }
}

func createInstance<T>(type:T.Type) -> T where T:Initializable {
    return type.init()
}
```

test:

```swift
let a = createInstance(type: SuperBar.self)
print("SuperBar: \(a.self)")
let b = createInstance(type: Bar.self)
print("Bar: \(b.self)")
```

result:

```
init SuperBar
SuperBar: __lldb_expr_22.SuperBar
init Bar
init SuperBar
Bar: __lldb_expr_22.Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force cast it if you know exactly the type of the generic.

```
let emptyObject:T = NSObject() as! T
```

Obviously this defeats the purpose of the generic class, but it can be useful for some default values or base class functionality as was in my case.

This is also dangerous and will crash if type `T` is not `NSObject`

Comment: This sure will crash for all non NSObject types.