# Swift generics: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to access class property

Tags: ios, generics, swift, exc-bad-access

It seems a class, which uses generics in swift, sometimes cannot properly determine object type.

Consider the following model structure:

```
class BaseModel: NSObject, Equatable, Printable {

    var id: String = ""

    override var description: String {
        return "id: \(id)"
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? BaseModel {
            return object.id == id
        }
        else {
            return super.isEqual(object)
        }
    }
}

class Image: BaseModel {

    var image: UIImage!

}
```

I also have parsers, which should parse/serialize objects:

```
class AbstractParser<T: BaseModel where T: Equatable>: NSObject {

    func convertFromParseObject(object: NSObject) -> T {
        var entity = T()
        ......

        return updateEntityWithParseObject(object, entity: entity)
    }

    func updateEntityWithParseObject(object: NSObject, entity: T) -> T {
        fatalError("This method must be overridden")
    }

}


class ImageParser<T: Image>: AbstractParser<Image> {

    override func updateEntityWithParseObject(object: NSObject, entity: Image) -> Image {
        println("\(entity)")
        println("\(entity.id)")
        // The line below outputs BaseModel, shouldn't it be Image instead?
        println("\(NSStringFromClass(entity.classForCoder))")
        // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here:
        println("\(entity.image)")
        return entity
    }

}
```

The app crashes when I try to access `entity.image`.

For some reasons Swift thinks that `entity` object is `BaseModel`, not `Image`.

Playground file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6agzpK_lR6JQUlhMFoxaGw1akU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What if you add a `createNewEntity()` to `AbsractParser` and then override it in `ImageParser`? Does changing your line `var entity = createNewEntity()` fix it?

Comment: Yes, it does. But in this case I'd have to add `createNewEntity()` method to every subclass - that's makes code ugly :(

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25352248/2708650

Comment: No, that doesn't work

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26284281/3804019 . `required override init() {  super.init() }` and `(T.self as T.Type)()`

Comment: Thanks, that seems working as well. Can you please add it as an answer?